# What is the Vanadurga Mahavidya Pancasati Mantra

Tags: mantras

samudrah uttere teere
maricho nama rakshasah
tasya mutra pureeshabhyam
hutasanam samaya samaya svaha
..... this is one mantra I found in 'vanadurga pancasati'. can anyone tell me the source and precise explanation to this mantra.